# Assigning value of inbuilt qsort() fucntion in C to another array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to use the inbuilt qsort() function in C to sort an array. Below is the code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main(void) {
    int size,i;
    printf("Enter the size of strings:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int a[size],identity[size];

    printf("***********************************************************\n");
    printf("Enter the first string:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);


    printf("Before sorting A is: \n");
    for( i = 0 ; i < size; i++ ) {
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    identity = qsort(a, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( i = 0 ; i < size; i++ ) {
      printf("%d ", identity[i]);
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Since I am from Python programming practices, I am not understanding how to make the array called **identity** hold the value of sorted array a , which I believe is the output of qsort()

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: [**`qsort()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) sorts the inbound data in-place. If you want it somewhere else, copy it there and then sort *that* array.

Comment: Note: `*(int*)a - *(int*)b` is a problem should the subtraction over/underflow.  Better to use `(*(int*)a > *(int*)b) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b)`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is returned from `qsort`, it simply sorts your array in-place. The `void` return type at the start of the prototype specifies lack of a return value:

```
void qsort(void *arr, size_t num, size_t sz, int (*fn)(const void*, const void*));
```

Hence you call it as:

```
qsort (a, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
```

and the "return value" is the array `a` itself, sorted according to the parameters you passed in.

That means you have no original array at the end, unless you make a copy of it first. If you *really* need to have a new sorted array (it's unusual), you can use something like:

```
int *identity = malloc (size * sizeof(int));
if (identity == NULL)
    complainBitterlyAndExit();
memcpy (identity, a, size * sizeof(int));
qsort (identity, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

// Now have original a and sorted identity.
// Need to free (identity) at some point.
```

Answer (score 1):

In default qsort function return void so you use following code

qsort(a, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

```
    printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
    for( i = 0 ; i < size; i++ ) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
```